# How can i solve "Failed to send email : No Recipient"? Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling

I have problem with my project using google app script, for example, i have 7 row: First to fifth row is filled with email, it works perfectly, then i jumped to seventh row, which is sixth row is empty, i filled seventh with email but it didnt works and send message "failed to send email: no recipient". So my problem is i can't send email if some row is empty. it must in sequence row. Please if anyone know of this, i would really appreciate, thanks

my code =

```
function sender() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEETID).getSheetByName('Surat Memo');
  const temp = DriveApp.getFileById(DOCID);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDERID);

  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const rows = data.slice(1);
  rows.forEach((row,index)=>{
    if(row[15]==''){
    const file = temp.makeCopy(folder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText('{Tanggal}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{Satker}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{Nomor Surat}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{Nomor}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{Kode E1}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{Perihal}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{Pemesan}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{Arsip}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{Penanggung Jawab}', row[13]);
    doc.setName(row[9]+row[0]);
    const blob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    doc.saveAndClose();


    const email = row[14];
    const subject = row[9] + '_' + row[2] + '_new file created ';
    const messageBody = 'Hi, Berikut Kode Penomoran UKPBJ';
    
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:email,
      subject:subject,
      htmlBody:messageBody,
      attachments: [blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    });

    const tempo = sheet.getRange(index+2,16,1,1);
    tempo.setValue(new Date());
    Logger.log(row);
    file.setTrashed(true);
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: Looks like `row[14];` is empty and therefore the email recipient is also empty (hence the error message) . This is likely true for for at least one of the rows being evaluated

Comment: row[14] is refers to colomn that i used to fill all email, like ive been asked, example i have 10 rows in this colomns, first to six ,in sequence i filled with email is ok, but if i jumped to tenth row, it cant send email, the row cant be blank and must in sequence. idk to solve this.

Comment: Use an if statement in your loop.

Comment: yes i figure it out, just put this before mailapp    if (email == "") return;

Answer (score 0):

yes it's mandatory fill with true email,
alternative you can fill in one cell, and get the value with code :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var email=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Email');
var emailAddress = email.getRange(2,1).getValue();
```

note : content cell B1(2,1) : user1@email.com,user2@email.com etc

Comment: This does not really solve the original problem.  Please read [answer]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).